# What is the significance of yaksha prashna? Are there any other such prominent scenarios?

Tags: mahabharata, dharma

I found wiki article on yaksha prashna [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaksha_Prashna). Where can I find the elaborated explanation on  this?

I observe these sort of question & answer sessions, discourses, arguments appear in our epics which apparently seems like essence of dharma.

Can someone please list other such prominent scenarios?

Answer (score 2):

1. There is the Nahusha Prasna episode in the MahaBharata Vana Parva and also appears in Bhagavatam.

And of course there is the

2. [prasnOpanishad](http://sivanandaonline.org/public_html/?cmd=displaysection&section_id=583) and the
3. [prasnOttara ratna mAlika by Sankaracharya](http://www.sanskritebooks.org/2009/04/prasnottara-ratna-malika-of-sankaracharya-sanskrit-english/).

Comment: You should add links for the Nahusha Prashna episode.  It comprises [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03179.htm) and [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03180.htm) of the Vana Parva of the Mahabharata.  But where in the Srimad Bhagavatam is the Nahusha Prashna episode?  As far as I can tell, only [this verse](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/6/13/16) and [this verse](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/18/3) of the Srimad Bhagavatam even mention Nahusha being turned into a snake, and I can't find any mention of the conversation between Nahusha and Yudhishthra.

Comment: Also, you just linked to a summary of the Prashna Upanishad.  Here's the whole thing: http://www.advaita.it/library/prasna.htm

Answer (score 1):

***Where can I find the elaborated explanation on [Yaksha Prashna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaksha_Prashna)?***

There's a short book on this, in English, about 100 pages long:

- A Hindu Primer: YAKSHA PRASHNA by Dr. A. V. Srinivasan (Available on [Amazon.com](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007HEGPS8) and [Amazon.in](http://www.amazon.in/Hindu-Primer-YAKSHA-PRASHNA-ebook/dp/B007HEGPS8/))

A free, but incomplete, version of the book is available on the publisher's website [here](http://www.periplusbooks.com/india_texts/yaksha/yp00.html).

If you understand Telugu, [Sri Samavedam Shanmukha Sarma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samavedam_Shanmukha_Sarma) covered both Nahusha and Yaksha Prashna in good depth during his recent (April 2015) 18-day discourse on Mahabharatam.

- [Nahusha Prashna on YouTube (Day 9)](https://youtu.be/8wMhgDcmYhA?t=5376) (lasts about 30 mins. from t=5376)
- [Yaksha Prashna on YouTube (Day 10)](https://youtu.be/JL3x7P-7eQc?t=3600) (lasts about 1 hour from t=3600)